# SEO for websites with similar content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, negative-seo

We have 3 businesses, located in different areas, with different names.  They have different domains, and do not cross reference each other.

The business is the same function (medical), and branded differently, however to make things easy we triplicated the main website.  Google now ommits the 2nd and 3rd business (the least busy) when googling.  I have checked and the pages are on Google, however it omits them from search results.

Is it sufficient to change the meta tags and some content for them to be seen as separate sites and not duplicates?

We have gone through and setup separate my business pages etc.

Comment: How much is "some content"?   How many pages? What percentage are you proposing changing?

Comment: Well, it was all the same except for a change in business names.  We have gone in and modified the content, changed sentences to say the same but have some different text.  Site stricture and pages are the same.

Answer (score 1):

With duplicate Google content, it can be difficult to determine which web page is relevant to a particular search query.

Possible Solution: Set in the content of your main (or one of the three) website all the information that you duplicate for your three businesses, so to speak, create the basic information that represents your business. On the websites of your individual businesses, clearly indicate the link to the business represented on the main website. For all duplicate content, link (possibly with anchors #) to the relevant information on the main website.

For example, on the main website, you have created a detailed description of a drug or medical procedure. This same drug or procedure is offered by all three of your businesses. In the content of all three websites, set the name of the drug or procedure and create a text link or button with a link (mobile friendly) to the detailed description on the main website.

This will create a clear signal to Google about the canonical content for the drug and procedure. At the same time, it will create a localization signal for this drug and procedure in your three businesses.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake every webmaster repeat while having a lot of pages with the same services across different locations. For example movers and packaging services sites what they do, just change the city name and cost in the content rest whole content remain the same for the pages.
**It is Bad for SEO**
Best to do:

Focus on improving the quality of your content and try to reduce the number of pages with a similar scenario.

I hope this will help to you